# How to detect whether a solenoid is actually attached to a MOSFET?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet

An injector is usually switched to ground to turn it on using a an N channel Mosfet. But how does the MCU knows when this is disconnected?

[image]

I'm trying to drive a solenoid, but if the solenoid is disconnected, I'd like my MCU to know that.

Comment: forget your whole question .... what is the thing that you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello Jsotola,
I'm trying to drive a solenoid, but if the solenoid is disconnected I'd love to be able to know through the MCU that is

Comment: The knock sensor does not detect the combustion « pulse » for that cylinder...

Comment: @DonP I added that crucial piece of info to your question; it changes everything. The thing you're trying to do is **not** similar.

Comment: Surprise: you'll have to connect it to the MCU. Voltage divider + high resistant series resistor to limit current. 3 resistors and maybe some decouping cap. If you wish to measure current instead of voltage, then a shunt resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're asking and what you're trying to do a very different things.

So, a modern ECU is a complex device with literally hundreds of actors and sensors attached. Especially, there will be sensors that observe whether the explosion in the cyclinder happens, there will be gasoline flow sensors, exhaust gas sensors… plenty of data from which an ECU can infer something went wrong during operation of the motor, and quite possibly also specifically that an injector doesn't work. Whether it knows *why* that injector doesn't work is a different question; I don't think it needs to!

What you're trying to do is a slight bit easier. You're not observing a complete car's drive. You're observing a solenoid.

So, simplest solution I could think of without actually just sensing the current with a shunt resistor, which brings isolation problems:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU1mVe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In non-operation, the digital input will be reliably high. But the switching on and: especially the switching off impulse as seen through the capacitor will be very different whether there is a solenoid attached or not; you should be able to register that.

Notice that all the component values are examples only; you probably want a smaller C1 if your solenoid is large, and lower-valued resistors. Maybe a pair of TVS diodes might be a good thing, too, to protect your microcontroller – but that really depends on your microcontroller, switching speed, the solenoid, and your ability to detect short pulses. Most microcontrollers can be programmed to register a sudden edge on an input – be it as an interrupt, or as a counter increase – but if yours doesn't, you'll need to poll that input, so that you might miss very short pulses.

Comment: Might also want to add a 10k series resistor towards the MCU for current limit purposes. TVS shouldn't be needed if there's a proper flyback diode across the coil, as in the OP's schematic.

Comment: @Lundin I wanted to be a bit extra careful – the idea was to sense the ringing, and that ringing might even go below ground voltage under bad circumstances (repeated switching etc)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good solution. So the capacitor will allow current to pass through but only for a brief moment, kind of like a toggle?
Yes, the MCU can read interrupt on select digital pins. I'll use that with a timeout, where if no pulse is seen within x period throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

First: ask yourself what failure are you trying to guard against. That is what problem you are tying to solve.

If the problem you want to detect is a wiring error during manufacturing then just testing that the solenoid is connected is a good solution.

If you want to detect that the MCU is causing some mechanical action, then consider sensing the mechanical activation. For example you could use a Hall sensor to detect movement of the rod in the solenoid. A second coil can give a transient response as the rod moves. Electro-mechanical components are typically more failure prone than solid-state electronics.

The solenoid has some wire resistance. In fact a coil (in relays for sure) is typically wound to have a resistance that will produce more than the activation current when the specified voltage is applied. So you can model the solenoid as an inductor and a resistor in series.

Depending on the system, solenoid current may make a significant change in the current drawn from the power supply. Maybe this is easy to measure.

Place a resistor in series with the coil. Make sure the resistance is small enough that it won't reduce coil current enough to prevent activation. If the solenoid is in the circuit there will be current flow and hence a voltage across this resistor.

Other current sensing methods that maybe easier to interface direct to an MCU are Hall sensors, current transformers (transient response).

As suggested in the other post you can put a small sense resistor between the MOSFET source and ground. An op-amp can be used to gain this small signal up to a voltage that is easily measured bu the MCU.

Now that I know the Solenoid could use up to 210 W. I think you could just amplify the Vds of the MOSFET. Even a large FET will some measureable voltage across its drain to source with thus much current flow. Another idea is if you have a wiring harness of any kind for this you could use wire resistance as a sense resistor for the solenoid current. The advantage of using a sense resistor is that you can digitize the voltage across it when no current flows before activating the solenoid and use that to subtract  the offset and improve your measurement.  You could apply this technique to a very low resistance say 0.1 mOhms or less.

Comment: I want to throw a fault code when the solenoid has an open circuit. 

This is to alert the end user something is wrong with his connection.

A hall effect sensor is too expensive and involves too much complication for both manufacturing and end user installation.

The option of placing a resistor in series and measuring the voltage difference is more acceptable. Actually this was my intended solution but it would likely use up two analog pins. Only issue is that this solenoid can draw up to 210 watts.